# Setting href on javascript ignores rails root path

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ldap

I have a Rails 6 application that doesn't use a regular sql-ish database, I do searches on an LDAP directory, and because of that, I don't use regular models for users, for example.

In one of my pages, I ask the user to input a person ID and then click a "Search" button, and through javascript I grab the id and pass it into the "Search" button href. As you can see here:

example.html.erb

```
<form class="d-flex">
    <input id="input" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Person's ID"></input>
    <a id="search" class="btn btn-outline-success">Search</a>
</form>
```

example.js

```
const inputPerson = document.getElementById('input')
const searchPerson = document.getElementById('search')

searchPerson.addEventListener('click', () => {
  searchPerson.setAttribute("href", `/people/${inputPerson.value}`);
})
```

So here comes the problem:
In my machine, running `rails s` and testing it, it works fine, as it redirects to `localhost:3000/people/12345example`
But my website runs in an url that looks like this: `shared-url.com/myappname`
So I expected the href on production would look like `shared-url.com/myappname/people/12345example` but it's actually coming up as `shared-url.com/people/12345example`, and of course it fails as this url does not exist at all...

I have `config.relative_url_root = '/myappname'` in my config/environments/production.rb, is there any other config I should have set for it to work like that? I know I could just change the javascript href, but I believe there's something I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you omit the leading `/`? Might be a case of absolute URL (triggered by the presence of the `/`) vs appended URL (might have to do concatenation, something like `setAttribute('href'. window.location.href + \`/people/${inputPerson.value}\`)`)

Comment: @TimLewis that was absolutely the case! removed `/` and it works, thanks!

Comment: oh, by the way, @TimLewis in the case that I'm not at home page, what should I use? let's say I'm in `shared-url.com/myappname/people` and I want to redirect to `shared-url.com/myappname/groups`, in a way that it would work both locally (without the /myappname/ prefix) and on my server (with the /myappname/ prefix)

Comment: actually, pretend I'm in `shared-url.com/myappname/people/123`

Comment: Yeah, that's the other issue; omitting the `/` definitely works if you're on the correct "base" URL you want to append to, but redirecting altogether wouldn't work the same way. For that, you'll have to make the `shared-url.com/myappname` available to JS, and set the URL with that included. Maybe use a `.js.erb` file instead of a plain `.js` file, so you can include the base URL via a Rails helper? Like `const baseUrl = '<%= ... %>';` (not sure _what_ the helper would be, but that's the general idea)